# How can I make text in a TextView unclickable in the layout XML?

Tags: android, android-layout, textview, tablerow

I have different table rows, each of it contains some information text which should not be clickable and not selectable. But when I run this in the emulator, the text is always clickable.

That means, when I click on any text block, its color changes to a dark grey. I don't want it to change. I want it to do nothing.

Surely, I could set the dark grey to the text color so the user doesn't see that he clicks anything, but this is not what I want.

I already tried different attributes as you can see in the example, but nothings help. Moreover, what do I actually have to set not clickable, the TableRow or the TextView inside the TableRow?

Here is an example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
    >
    <ScrollView 
            android:id="@+id/scrollView"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal">
    <TableLayout 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:stretchColumns="*"
            android:clickable="false">
        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:background="#777777"
            android:clickable="false">
            <TextView 
                 android:id="@+id/heading"
                 android:text="This is the cool heading"             
                 android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                 android:textSize="14sp"
                 android:paddingLeft="5sp"
                 android:paddingRight="5sp"
                 android:paddingTop="2sp"
                 android:paddingBottom="2sp"
                 android:textStyle="bold" 
                 android:clickable="false"  
                 />
        </TableRow>
         <TableRow
             android:clickable="false"
             android:linksClickable="false"
             android:focusable="false"
             android:focusableInTouchMode="false">
            <TextView
                 android:text="This is example text. It should not be clickable, but it is."
                 android:textSize="14sp"
                 android:paddingLeft="5sp"
                 android:paddingRight="5sp"
                 android:paddingTop="2sp"
                 android:paddingBottom="2sp"
                 android:scrollHorizontally="false"
                 android:inputType="textMultiLine"
                 android:linksClickable="false"
                 android:clickable="false"
                 android:focusable="false"
                 android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
                 android:layout_width="0sp"
                 />
               </TableRow>
              </TableLayout>
              </ScrollView>
              </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: is the whole tablerow is changed to a dark grey or only the text inside the text is changed to darkgrey?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I found the solution, when I add `android:longClickable="false"` to the TextView, it works. And I only need those two settings in TextView in all:

```
android:longClickable="false"
android:clickable="false"
```

Settings in TableRow are not needed.

Answer (score 4):

You need to put these attritbutes:

```
         android:clickable="false"
         android:linksClickable="false"
         android:focusable="false"
         android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
```

In your textview element also. Right now you're just disabling the row, not the individual elements within the row.

Comment: my doubt is if we blocked every thing for tablerow how can the click event occur for textView that present inside Tablerow?

Comment: Uh, what? Why is that even a concern? Have you tried it to confirm this concern?

Comment: actually @Bevor already tried different attributes that he mentioned and his last Textview shows that he added all the attritbutes you mentioned above.

Comment: @Kurtis:
See the last TextView.